# Need understanding of goroutines

Tags: go, goroutine

I am new to Go language programming and learning it step by step.
While practicing it, I found random behavior of goroutines.
If I call goroutine (function having sleep of 1 second), some times it completed successfully and some times it doesn't:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func t(i int) {
    fmt.Println("In func t")
    time.Sleep(1)
}

func t1(i int) {
    fmt.Println("In func t1")
    time.Sleep(1)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello Good Morning")
    go t(1)
    t1(2)
    time.Sleep(5)
    fmt.Println("End of func main")
}
```

O/p 1 :

```
  Hello Good Morning
  In func t1
  In func t
  End of func main
```

O/p 2 :

```
  Hello Good Morning
  In func t1
  End of func main
```

Could someone explain why goroutine is not guaranteeing the execution of that goroutine function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Program execution](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution):

> When the function `main` returns, the program exits. It does not wait
>   for other (non-main) goroutines to complete.

1- `main` is goroutine too, you need to wait for other goroutines to finish, and you may use

```
time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
```

for 5 Seconds wait, try it on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xUAcqJqhOv):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func t(i int) {
    fmt.Println("In func t")
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}

func t1(i int) {
    fmt.Println("In func t1")
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello Good Morning")
    go t(1)
    t1(2)
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("End of func main")
}
```

output:

```
Hello Good Morning
In func t1
In func t
End of func main
```

And see Docs:

> ```
> // Sleep pauses the current goroutine for at least the duration d.
> // A negative or zero duration causes Sleep to return immediately.
> func Sleep(d Duration)
> ```

---

2- You may use `sync.WaitGroup` to wait for other goroutines, try it on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/snxphtgx0v):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var w sync.WaitGroup

func say(s string) {
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
    w.Done()
}

func main() {
    w.Add(1)
    go say("A")

    w.Add(1)
    say("B")

    w.Wait()
}
```

output:

```
B
A
A
B
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. If you return from `main` without having explicitly waited for your
   goroutine to finish, there's no guarantee that it will finish before
   the program exits.
2. The argument type of `time.Sleep()` is `time.Duration`,
   the units of which are nanoseconds. Since you're barely delaying at
   all, it's not surprising that your results were random. If you sleep
   for a more substantial amount of time in `main`, you should see both
   lines printed (although it isn't guaranteed).

If you need to wait for a goroutine to finish, there are various ways to do that (e.g, channels and `sync.WaitGroup`).

You may want to go through [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org) and/or take a look at [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.